# Depth of field is not being rendered in Blender Internal

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, depth-of-field

I have quite an annoying thing, that I don't know how to do.
I'm about to render a small clip, but I don't know how to enable Depth of Field in animations render to make it visible in the final product. It is visible in 3D view, but not in the render. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I use the in-built renderer, nothing special. I'm not using compositor.

[image: That's what I see in render mode.]
[image: That's what I see in render mode.]
[image: It still not working, even though, I set everything as I could see on the picture.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the compositor :)

The Camera settings sets an object as your focus point and the Defocus node uses this for calculations. Or, leave it blank and use the Defocus node settings for distance calculations.

In the Render layers settings, ensure you've added a Z pass.

[image]

Comment: Alright, I set everything, just as you, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working, it just not visible in 3D View's render. I have to render it as I would to save it. Thank you!

Comment: Ah - you wanted DOF in the live Rendered VIEW. As you've discovered, no-one can help you there. Rendered View (as opposed to an actual render) is meant only as an indicative idea of uncomposited textures and lighting. Because DOF is a composited effect in BI, you won't see this being reflected in the live Rendered View. Nor will you see other compositing effects, such as gamma correction, composited blur, distortions, etc. DOF is easily done in Solid view on the fly, but in rendered view it's a major performance hit. Nor is DOF available in Cycles' Rendered view - same problem.