# (Internal) Easy Way To Focus?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

so I was wondering if there is an easy way to add camera focus to your scene in internal? I have tried adding nodes and a plain axis but it just is really hard to control. Is there an easy way to add focus? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "*add focus*" and "*scene in internal*", it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question and provide some screenshots and feedback about why "*adding nodes*" doesn't work for you.

Comment: I mean defocus, like when you focus a camera. The nodes don't work for me because the settings I use and the plain axis just doesn't make for a good focus setting. I don't know what to add screenshots of :/ Scene in internal is just the scene set up i have.

Comment: Well a screenshot of your scene and node setup and scene might be useful for starters. Also state why non of the previously provided methods work for you  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/depth-of-field-f-stop-not-doing-anything or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/depth-of-field-is-not-being-rendered-in-blender-internal Also see https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?143815-How-do-you-DoF-with-Blender-Internal and https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Composite_Nodes/Setups/Depth_Of_Field