# How do I add a focus effect to a scene in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blur

So I'm trying to render a scene in which a character is taking a photo of another character, The angle will be from the side of the second character who is posing for a photo. I want the character to be blurred to give it a focus effect, How do I do this in the simplest way possible? Keep in mind I am in blender render.

Comment: Fastest is probably do it in post production with a blur node on the compositor

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71563/depth-of-field-is-not-being-rendered-in-blender-internal?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/depth-of-field-f-stop-not-doing-anything